# How can I replace the last character of a string with another character in bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell

I am working on a small code in bash, but I am stuck on a small problem.
I have a string, and I want to replace the last letter of that string with `s`.

For example: I am taking all the files that end in `c` and replacing the last `c` with `s`.

```
for file in *.c; do
   # replace c with s  
   echo $file
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 14):

```
for file in *.c; do 
   echo "${file%?}s"
done
```

In parameter substitution, ${VAR%PAT}  will remove the last characters matching PAT from variable VAR.
Shell patterns `*` and `?` can be used as wildcards.

The above drops the final character, and appends "s".

Answer (score 4):

Use [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html). The following accomplishes suffix replacement. It replaces one instance of `c` anchored to the right with `s`.

```
for file in *.c; do
   echo "${file/%c/s}"  
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rename` utility if you would want to get away with loop

```
rename -f 's/\.c$/.s/' *.c
```