# Replace the last character in string

Tags: bash, macos

How can I just replace the last character (it's a `}`) from a string? I need everything before the last character but replace the last character with some new string.

I tried many things with awk and sed but didn't succeed.

For example:

```
...\\tx4535\\tx5102\\tx5669\\tx6236\\tx6803\\pardirnatural
\\f0
}'
```

should become:

```
...\\tx4535\\tx5102\\tx5669\\tx6236\\tx6803\\pardirnatural
\\f0
\\cf2 Its red now
}'
```

This replaces the last occurrence of:

```
}
```

with

```
\\cf2 Its red now
}
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but very close: [How can I replace the last character of a string with another character in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19169175/3266847)

Answer (score 1):

sed would do this:

```
# replace '}' in the end
echo '\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural \f0 }' | sed 's/}$/\\cf2 Its red now}/'

# replace any last character
echo '\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural \f0 }' | sed 's/\(.\)$/\\cf2 Its red now\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the trailing `}` could be done like this (with `$` as the PS1 prompt and `>` as the PS2 prompt):

```
$ str="...\\tx4535\\tx5102\\tx5669\\tx6236\\tx6803\\pardirnatural
> \\f0
> }"
$ echo "$str"
...\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural
\f0
}
$ echo "${str%\}}\cf2 It's red now
}"
...\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural
\f0
\cf2 It's red now
}
$
```

The first 3 lines assign your string to my variable `str`.  The next 4 lines show what's in the string.  The 2 lines:

```
echo "${str%\}}\cf2 It's red now
}"
```

contain a (grammar-corrected) substitution of the material you asked for, and the last lines echo the substituted value.

Basically, `${str%tail}` removes the string `tail` from the end of `$str`; I remember `%` ends in 't' for tail (and the analogous `${str#head}` has hash starting with 'h' for head).

See [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the Bash manual for the remaining details.

If you don't know the last character, you can use a `?` metacharacter to match the end instead:

```
echo "${str%?}and the extra"
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a string with newlines

```
str=$(printf "%s\n%s\n%s" '\\tx4535\\tx5102\\tx5669\\tx6236\\tx6803\\pardirnatural' '\\f0' "}'")
```

Now you look for the last `}` in your string and replace it including a newline.
The `$` makes sure it will only replace it at the last line, `&` stands for the matches string.

```
echo "${str}" |sed '$ s/}[^}]$/\\\\cf2 Its red now\n&/'
```

The above solution only works when the `}` is at the last line. It becomes more difficult when you also want to support `str2`:

```
str2=$(printf "Extra } here.\n%s\nsome other text" "${str}")
```

You can not match the `}` on the last line. Removing the address `$` for the last line will result in replacing all `}` characters (I added a `}` at the beginning of `str2`). You only want to replace the last one.
Replacing once is forced with `..../1`. Replacing the last and not the first is done by reversing the order of lines with `tac`. Since you will `tac` again after the replacement, you need to use a different order in your `sed`replacement string.

```
echo "${str2}" | tac |sed 's/}[^}]$/&\n\\\\cf2 Its red now/1' |tac
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk ' BEGIN { RS=OFS=FS="" } $NF="\\\\cf2 Its red now\n}"' file
```

- `RS=""` sets `RS` to an empty record (change it to suit your needs)
- `OFS=FS=""` separates characters each to its own field
- `$NF="\\\\cf2 Its red now\n}"` replaces the char in the last field (`$NF=}`) with the quoted text

Comment: Your command gives me 2 curly braces:
...\\tx4535\\tx5102\\tx5669\\tx6236\\tx6803\\pardirnatural
\\f0
}\\cf2 Its red now
} #Please correct it.

Comment: @ClaesWikner It replaces the last character in the string _it's a `}`_. If it's not the last, whatever is in the end gets replaced and the original `}` stays there.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/\\f0/,"\\f0\n\\\\\cfs Its red now")}1' file

...\\tx4535\\tx5102\\tx5669\\tx6236\\tx6803\\pardirnatural
\\f0
\\cfs Its red now
}'
```